# Can I specify the model (e.g. "video") in the Google Cloud Speech-to-Text api when using the gcloud tool?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, gcloud, speech-to-text

Google's speech-to-text service has several possible models to use for transcribing speech to text (standard, video, phone call, etc). Google provides [documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/enhanced-models) on using these models when sending requests to their speech-to-text api from Python or via curl. But I am using `gcloud ml speech recognize` to make requests to that API, and want to be able to specify the model to use. I've read pages and pages of documentation to figure this out, but no luck yet.

My command-line script:

```
gcloud ml speech recognize test.wav --language-code=EN --useEnhanced=true
```

I've also tried `--model=video` instead of `--useEnhanced=true`.

Google's response:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ml.speech.recognize) unrecognized arguments: --useEnhanced=true

To search the help text of gcloud commands, run:
  gcloud help -- SEARCH_TERMS
```

Please help! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to get it working with the gcloud tool but I was able to do it "manually" with cURL. Follow the docs here: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-protocol. Make sure to create a service account with the proper role, download the resulting private key, and run `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path-to-credentials.json`. Then create a JSON file with your request. Mine looked like this:

```json
{
    "config": {
        "languageCode": "en-US",
        "useEnhanced": true,
        "model": "video"
    },
    "audio": {
        "uri": "gs://bucket/audio.flac"
    }
  }
```

Then just execute the cURL command the docs suggest for the recognize endpoint (taking care to change the file name to the JSON you created) and you should be good to go.

Here are the docs for the recognize endpoint: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/speech/recognize. You can click-through to the RecognitionConfig and RecognitionAudio objects to see what you can include in your JSON file.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I ended up using a similar solution: from the doc here: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-python I used the python library.

Comment: You can also embed your audio file into the JSON by [base64 encoding it](https://www.base64encode.org/), and placing it in the `"audio": { "content": "...." }` section. Then you can run the curl command like this: `curl --request POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data "@json-file.json" "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1p1beta1/speech:recognize?key=YOUR-API-KEY-HERE"`

Answer (score -1):

For specifying the default model example "video" you can use it as a group:

```
gcloud ml video // example
```

This is the link with the gcloud refence: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml-engine/#GCLOUD-WIDE-FLAGS

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but `gcloud ml video` is a different model, it's used for processing visual video content. The documentation I linked to shows that there is a video-specific model _for speech recognition_, not for processing visual video content.

Comment: I've updated my question to prevent future confusion